# Data availability on a HART device network configured for multi-drop mode

Tags: digital-communications, plc, serial-bus, industrial

We have 2 flow meters on an equipment installation that are HART-capable. As they are installed today, configuring these devices in multi-drop mode would be much easier than running additional wire for a point-to-point configuration that seems to be more common in the HART realm of things. One requirement we have is to pull 4 parameters of information (PV/SP/TV/QV) from each meter, and I am combing through the protocol to try and understand 2 significant questions:

1.) Can PV/SP/TV/QV still be pulled if the device/network is in a multi-drop configuration?

2.) Does the 1200 bps / "roughly 2 parameters per second" apply here? Should I expect the real-time update of 4 values from a meter to take about 2 seconds? And if I have 2 meters, totaling 8 values, would the full sweep be expected to take about 4 seconds?

Thanks!